# Accessing to object's methods and attributes throws to error in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have this declaration of an object inside an `Angular.js` module:

```
    $scope.Stack = function () {
        this.top = null;
        this.size = 0;
    };
```

And when i call `push` method of that object i get `undefined` error:

```
    $scope.Stack.push = function (data) {
        return this.size;
    };
```

Why?

Comment: `Push` method is defined for an `array`. You should learn arrays and how to push data in an array.

Comment: @Vineet: no, push is my custom defined function and attached to that object

Comment: My guess is that you have hit against the `this` problem in JavaScript. The `this` instance when you are calling the `push` method is not the `this` that you are expecting. How are you calling `push`? Please provide more code.

Comment: @AndrewEisenberg: my whole code is this. i call it like this: $scope.Stack.push(1);

Comment: Yup. I see what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you are doing what you really want to do.  You are creating a function called `Stack` and then the code:

```
$scope.Stack.push(1)
```

Invokes the `push` property on the `Stack` function (which doesn't exist).  More likely, you want to create an instance of a `Stack` and call `push` on that.

```
var myStack = new $scope.Stack();
myStack.push(1);  // Yay!
```

This will work in most cases. But just beware that `this` is dynamically defined. I suggest you read up on [`this` at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).